# Emulator not working in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

I followed this tutorial to create HelloWorld Android app.
I was able to start the emulator from eclipse.
But nothing seems to happen except this Android logo keeps flashing on.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0KXygm6.jpg]

Has anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: The emulator takes time to boot. Keep it running for a while and the home screen will likely show up.

Comment: Also, try to use the snapshot option. Like that you don't have to wait too long next time you start the emulator.

Comment: +1 for waiting, it can take forever sometimes.  If you've given it a reasonable amount of time and it still doesn't work, it may be useful to post your hardware specs and the emulator configurations to try and track down the issue.

Comment: this is not technical but worked for me...first run the app from eclipse,now when the emulator shows up close it after 4-5 seconds,again launch the app and let emulator open.

Comment: If your target is not Google API then try using HAXM

Answer (score 1):

You'd better wait about 10-15 (it depends on your computer). But if it doesn't work, try in command prompt:

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

If `adb` is not found, then you should move your directory to the folder, where `adb.exe` is located, for me it is
`C:\Users\Andranik\android-sdks\platform-tools`, therefore:

`cd C:\Users\Andranik\android-sdks\platform-tools` and after this execute upper commands.

This helps me.

Answer (score 0):

It's working.. It is simply super slow ;)

Keep waiting a while longer and it will boot eventually. It helps to choose smaller devices with less ram.

Just a heads up, loading devices like tablets or the newest phones can easily take you 20-30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for responding :) ...Then I assume the best way to test custom Android app is to by testing on an Android phone or tablet..right ?

Comment: Yeah in my opinion its pretty much impossible to actually create an app with only the emulator. If you can't afford to buy multiple phones/tablets, just buy 1 average and just sometimes take a day to test it on multiple emulators

Answer (score 0):

If you planned not to use Google API as target of your emulator then u can use **Intel x86 Hardware Accelerator(HAXM)**. Open your SDK manager then install ***Extras-->Intel x86 Hardware Accelerator(HAXM)***.Install it from

> sdk_path\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\IntelHaxm.exe (Windows)

Then on your emulator configuration choose **Intel Atom (x86)** as CPU/ABI rather than ARM.

Additionally you can set more ram to your AVD and check ***Use host GPU***  to speed up your emulator.